# Why does this expression return true in Firefox/Chrome and false in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have code similar to the following in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="submitMyForm" name="submitMyForm" checked="checked" />
```

When I tried using this code in an if statement, I realized it was returning true for Firefox/Chrome, but false for IE:

```
$('#submitMyForm').prop("checked")
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0uqpe8r/1/) to illustrate.

Why does IE interpret this expression differently? And, on a more practical note, what's an equivalent expression I can use that would evaluate to true in all browsers?

Comment: FYI `checked` is not a valid property for a hidden input. I would imagine this is the root of the inconsistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid (in HTML 5 anyway, earlier versions of HTML can't express the rule in DTDs but it is still non-confirming there). Only radio buttons and checkboxes may have a `checked` attribute. Hidden inputs may not. The difference you are experiencing is due to the browsers attempting to recover from the error in the HTML in different ways.

The sensible approach is to not use a hidden input with a checked attribute at all.

Possibly you could use a `data-checked` attribute instead. Then access it with `.data('checked')`.

You could also continue to use broken HTML and examine the attribute itself (instead of the property generated from it):

```
alert($('#submitMyForm').attr("checked"));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an old page - I think it was set up this way because the same form has 2 forms - it can either be an update or a create form. When using it as a create form, this checkbox element actually does exist - when using as an update form it doesn't so they tried to simulate it with this hidden field. I'll find a more correct way to code around it.

Comment: The hidden equivalent of a checked/unchecked checkbox is one which either exists or does not exist, not which has a checked state or not.

Comment: I think they were trying to use the same processing code for either variation of the form. So they wanted to be able to check `$('#submitMyForm').prop("checked")` regardless of which version of the form was in use. The actual code is a little more involved than the example (and I didn't do a good job of naming the element for the example), but that's the basic idea. Thanks for helping me pinpoint the issue, I'm going to rework the code so that it's correct html and more logically accomplishes what's needed